# Incurs_seek_penalty column of sys.dm_os_volume_stats

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

A new column, `incurs_seek_penalty`, was introduced in the SQL Server 2019 `sys.dm_os_volume_stats` DMF. This tinyint column is [not currently documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-volume-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Does anyone have information about the enumerated values returned in this column? I've seen values of 0 (bare metal server) and 2 (VM). I'm curious as to what these values mean and what other values might be returned. My internet search hasn't turned up anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is now officially documented, with the following values:

> Indicates the type of storage supporting this volume. Possible values are:
>
> 0: No seek penalty on this volume, typically when the storage device
> is PMM or SSD
>
> 1: Seek penalty on this volume, typically when the storage device is
> HDD
>
> 2: The storage type can't be determined when the volume is on a UNC
> path or mounted shares
>
> NULL: The storage type can't be determined on Linux operating system
>
> **Applies to:** SQL Server (starting with SQL Server 2019 (15.x))

It looks like this is related to the low level [`DEVICE_SEEK_PENALTY_DESCRIPTOR` structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntddstor/ns-ntddstor-_device_seek_penalty_descriptor) (thanks, LowlyDBA!) - possibly in an attempt to **check if a drive is an SSD or not** (that approach is also [discussed on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23363115/detecting-ssd-in-windows/33359142)).

It would still be interesting to know if this information about the storage is (or will be) used by SQL Server (e.g., for updated I/O cost estimates, or performance optimizations inside the storage engine).

Comment: Thanks, Josh. Hopefully the doc team will also reach out the the devs to document how the value is used too. I can see it could be for storage engine optimizations depending on device capability.

Comment: @DanGuzman My PR got closed without being merged, but Pedro Lopes came back and updated the docs page last week.  Still no info on whether the value is used in any way by the engine, but it's good to know we were pretty close to correct with our guesses 